# Getting current date and time with specific time zone for discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get the current date and time from a time zone (NZT) but am unsure how. Currently when I make a new date it's time zone is set to GMT-0 (or something like that, anyway not what I want). I need to be able to get the date and time in NZT (bot isn't run in New Zealand so if that's an issue then...) All help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you using luxon.
It is one of the best date-time dependencies and far better than the JS-Inbuilt date-time system.

The following code should give you what you need:

```js
const {
    DateTime
} = require('luxon');


var local = DateTime.local();
var rezoned = local.setZone("Pacific/Auckland");
```

If you really need the date Object to be formatted as adefault JavaScript Object, you can use the following code:

```js
const {
    DateTime
} = require('luxon');


function localDate() {

    let local = DateTime.local(); //initialize luxon Date-Object
    let rezonedString = local.setZone("Pacific/Auckland").toString(); //set timezone of Date-Object and convert to string
    var dateString = rezonedString.slice(0, -10) + "z"; //trim string to create default JavaScript Date-OBject
    var today = new Date(dateString); //convert dateString to JS Date-Object

    //fix Month index
    today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 1);
    return today;

}

//set variable today to localDate in NZ
var today = localDate();
```

> Note: this is a solution for JavaScript! This is because you tagged discord.js, which is a javaScript Framework for the Discord API

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this doesn't quite work as importing doesn't work. I get the error "import cannot be used ouside modules". I am using Replit if this makes any difference. (requiring works for other things like node-cron and discord.js)

Comment: I never had that error. But you could try using ```const { DateTime } = require('luxon');``` and see if that fixes your problem. At least that's how I used it in my code, I don't know how that import slipped into my answer there.

Comment: You have never declared tempToday. Is it meant to be local or rezonedString?

Comment: Changing tempToday to rezonedString fixed it! Thanks, my only issue is that it claims the month is the 5'th (April) when clearly it's the 6'th (June).

Comment: I never experienced this kind of behavior myself, but you can set the Date and Month of a date Object by using `#setMonth()` and  `#setDate()`. I have added this in my codeblock.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot! Though the date is correct it's just the month that was in the past!